# Create accumulated table by appending rows from previous years in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need to create accumulated dataset throughout the years in PowerQuery. It should append new rows from previous years up to 2040.

Explanation:

1. Europe/Q/DK/H/OP has 1 capacity in 2020
2. Europe/Q/DK/H/OP has 13 (accumulated 12 from 2020 and 1 from 2022) capacity in 2022
3. There is no new data for Europe/Q/DK/H/OP in the following years, meaning it has the same capacity between 2022-2040 so we are inserting new rows: Europe/Q/DK/H/OP with capacity 13 (2023,2024,2025...2040).
4. In 2026 We see new data being introduced. Those distinct rows (Region, Company, Country, LoR, Status) are not present in future years (2027-2040) so we are inserting them.
5. In 2027 Europe/Q with capacity 80 is introduced but also all records from previous years:

- Europe/Q/DK/H/OP/13/2027,
- Europe/Q/UK/L/An/80/2027,
- Europe/Q/NL/L/An/17.5/2027,
- Europe/Q/AE/L/An/80/2027

Afterwards, all those rows are inserted with changed Years up to 2040 and the same Capacity.

Example data:

| Region | Company | Year | Capacity | Country | LoR | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | Q | 2020 | 1 | DK | H | OP |
| Europe | Q | 2022 | 12 | DK | H | OP |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 80 | UK | L | An |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 17.5 | NL | L | An |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 80 | AE | L | An |
| Europe | Q | 2027 | 80 |  |  |  |

Desired output:

| Region | Company | Year | Capacity | Country | LoR | Status | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | Q | 2020 | 1 | DK | H | OP |  |
| Europe | Q | 2021 | 1 | DK | H | OP |  |
| Europe | Q | 2022 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2023 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2024 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2025 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 80 | UK | L | An |  |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 17.5 | NL | L | An |  |
| Europe | Q | 2026 | 80 | AE | L | An |  |
| Europe | Q | 2027 | 80 |  |  |  |  |
| Europe | Q | 2027 | 80 | UK | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2027 | 17.5 | NL | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2027 | 80 | AE | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2027 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2028 | 80 |  |  |  |  |
| Europe | Q | 2028 | 80 | UK | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2028 | 17.5 | NL | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2028 | 80 | AE | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2028 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| Europe | Q | 2029 | 80 |  |  |  |  |
| Europe | Q | 2029 | 80 | UK | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2029 | 17.5 | NL | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2029 | 80 | AE | L | An | Accumulated from the previous year |
| Europe | Q | 2029 | 13 | DK | H | OP | Accumulated from 2022 (either 1 row grouped (1 + 12 capacity) or 2 separate rows) |
| ... | ... | 2040 | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

Current code that calculates the capacity but is not appending the previous years:

```
= Table.Group(#"Some Previous steps", {"Company", "Region", "Year", "Country", "LoR", "Status"}, {{"Data", each let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1) in Table.AddColumn(a, "Accumulated Capacity [kt]", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(a[#"Capacity [kt]"],[Index]+1))) , type table }}),
```

Comment: Added explanation and changed a bit requirements so it is better understood what is needed to be achieved: dataset that accumulates the Capacity throughout the Year on distinct rows (Region, Company, Country, LoR, Status)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Good hint, but the code you have provided is not working correctly as it leaves in between years with 0. This code resolved the question. Thanks! :)

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Year", each {[Start up Year]..2040}),
#"Expanded Year" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Year"),
CalculateSum = Table.Group(#"Expanded Year", {"Company", "Year", "Region", "Country", "LoR", "Status"}, {{"Accumulated Capacity", each List.Sum([Capacity]), type nullable number}}),
```

Comment: You, fellow user, are a genius and a scholar. An excellent answer. Please remind me to answer more of your questions in the future

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you

```
 let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Year", "Capacity"})),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Year", each {2020..2030}),
#"Expanded Year" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Year"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Year", {"Region", "Company", "Year", "Country", "LoR", "Status"}, Source, {"Region", "Company", "Year", "Country", "LoR", "Status"}, "Base", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Base", {"Capacity"}, {"Capacity"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Table",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Capacity"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", {"Region", "Company", "Country", "LoR", "Status"}, {
    {"data", each 
    let Sort= Table.Sort(_,{{"Year", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Sort, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "CumTotal", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[Capacity],[Index]+1)))
    in #"Added Cum Total", type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Year", "CumTotal"}, {"Year", "CumTotal"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

I think you had the right idea, but needed to populate the missing years first